# How to interpret "ask somebody to verb" in this conext?

Tags: meaning

> If someone is in the room, **please ask them to leave, or book another room on the 2nd floor.**

I read this on a manual, and does the bold part mean:

> Please ask them to leave. Or please book another room on the 2nd
>   floor.

Or

> Please ask them to leave. Or please ask them to book another room on
>   the 2nd floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two verbs refer to **them**, the misleading may come from absence of the consecutive "to", which as you can see is missing here, but is potentially there.

> If someone is in the room, please ask them to leave, or to book another room on the 2nd floor.

- Please ask them to do this or that, if the former is unacceptable!

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous.

The "book" might be within the scope of the disjunction, or might not.

Over the last few minutes I have gone back and forth between thinking one interpretation or the other is more likely.

My conclusion is that it is actually ambiguous, and I have no grounds for deciding which interpretation was intended.

Comment: In terms of grammar it is ambiguous, but in terms of understanding, the only possible interpretation is that the former refers to them to, not to the listener, since their is no mentioning of that he should do the booking, which in this case would be absolutely a must, such an inclusion will remove the ambiguity and make the sense clear.

Comment: Though I should say, I agree with you, I hate it when they do it.

Comment: I don't agree, @SovereignSun: I still find it completely ambiguous. It is suggesting the reader do something, but whether it is suggesting they make another booking, or ask the people in the room to make another booking, I can't tell.